# How to implement CRL and OCSP for a Camel JMS application?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, digital-signature, ca, ocsp

We have a distributed `jms` application that runs with `spring-boot` on `oracle-linux` machines. For security considerations we need to `sign` and `verify` messages. We did do it by using `camel-xmlsecurity` with a self-signed certificate but security rules force us to use a `CA`, instead. So we need to provide `Certificate Revocation List (CRL)` and `Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP)` for the application.

It looks like `CRL` and `OCSP` support are provided usually by a third-party application like `Microsoft Exchange Server` in Windows and `openssl` in Linux, but I guess it should be possible in java native code level or probably by `camel`.

Where and how I can implement `CRL` and `OCSP`?

Comment: You can use openssl to build your certificates, CRLs an launch an OCSP responder. You can also do it with java using bouncycastle library, but it is a low level library, and build each part of the PKI you need requires a considerable amount of programming effort. I'm afraid that it is too broad for this question.

Comment: @pedrob I'm new to `PKI` concepts and I think my question was misleading. I don't want to launch a `CA`, there is already one that serves our company. We (as server) and our clients will receive certs from the CA for the kick, then in the application we need to check validity of the received certs from our clients by using `CRL` and/or `OCSP` for each message. I found [a piece of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38301283/java-ssl-certificate-revocation-checking/38523104#38523104) for doing so but am curious to know that if it is also possible by using a library like `bouncycastle`?

Comment: I got the concept, summarizing you want to validate the revocation of a certificate. From Java8 you can use PKIXRevocationChecker. The bouncycastle library also allows you to perform the validation step by step: 1) extract the revocation URLs (OCSP and / or CRL) from the certificate, 2) validate the certificate using the CRL or 3) make an OCSP request to the server 4) verify the answer (CRL/OCSP), including its digital  signature